# integrate $\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{9+4x^2}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> $$\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{9+4x^2}} $$

I understand I need to use $x=\frac{3}{2}\tan\theta$ trigonometric substitution

So I got to: $$\int {\frac{3}{2\cos^2\theta}\over \frac{3}{2} \tan\theta \sqrt{9+9\tan^2\theta}}=\int {\cos^2\theta\over 3\tan\theta \sec\theta}d\theta$$

how should I continue from here?

Comment: If you  want to do trig substitution, let $2x=3\tan\theta$.

Comment: Convert all functions to $\sin$ and $\cos$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just give a hint, solve it on your own.
substitute $x=\dfrac32\tan y$
and then integrate with respect to $y$. Finally substitute $y$ with $x$.
now you can reduce everything to sin and substitute sinx with a variable. you will get a cos term in the numerator. i think that should be enough

Answer (score 0):

Just take $x^2$ out of square root and let $u={1/x}$ and it converts into standard  ${\frac{1}{\sqrt{quadratic}}}$

$${\frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{9x^{-2}+4}}}$$
$$u={\frac1x}$$     $$du={\frac{-1}{x^2}}$$
$${\frac{-du}{\sqrt{9u^2+4}}}$$